# Is an ampersand (&) in a company name not ideal for Google or SEO?

Tags: seo, keywords, symbols

I am working on a site with a company name with an `&` in it.
An alternative is using `and` instead of `&`.

Does `&` have some disadvantages in a company name we have to know of? Does it effect SEO? Can Google 'work' with it?

Are there some other disadvantages?

**Update**

The domain name is not a problem, because there is used `and`. It's not a problem to use `and`, but in the logo is `&` used. So on site they want to use `&` also.

But i think people are going to search for the `and` version. It's easier to type `C and A` instead of `C&A` (certainly in my case). But when i'm using `&` on the site everywhere Google might not discover we mean the same. Or is that a crazy though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, a company name with a `&` is a trouble for domain names.

As you said, you need to find alternatives because you can't register a domain name with a `&` in the URL.

The main disadvantage I see is you need to register many domain names to cover all alternatives of the `&` in relation to the language of the users. And in your case, you can hope all these domain names are available.

You most probably know [the C&A company](http://www.c-and-a.com/). If you analyze their domain names, you can see they have many domains names to cover alternatives for each language. Example:

- for English users: `www.c-and-a.com`
- for French users: `www.c-et-a.fr`
- for Spanish users: `www.c-y-a.es`
- ...

Moreover, C&A needs to protect domain names they own. That's why, they most probably also registered all TLDs of `c-and-a`, `c-et-a`, `c-y-a`, etc. Compared to a single domain name with each language on a subdomain, it costs much money to register a domain name per language.

However, it's not impossible, you can copy the C&A system. For branding, they always use the term C&A. For SEO and Google, there is no impact because Google bots will analyze your domain without a `&`.

For Google users, this is not a problem because Google knows that `&` is a synonym of `and`. So, they can type one or the other, Google will show up your site in the SERPs (this is the case for C&A). If it's the case yet, you can work on branding on the Internet and Google will understand that this is the same company.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. I updated my question. The domain name is not a problem.

Comment: See my last paragraph.

Comment: I would like to add that Google easily recognizes the & as an *and* and will do a substitution resulting in and where required, but also index the &. This is done for the reasons we all understand. So any search for either C&A or C and A should return the same results with some preference for exact matches.