# Best alternative to character "&" in domain name

Tags: domains, domain-registration, name, character-set

The business name: **X&X Business**.
However, the domain name **x&xbusiness.example** is just not possible.

Is there a formal alternative or is there a convention so it can be used instead of the character **"&"** for the domain names?

Comment: "formal" and "convention" are very different.  Formal would mean that a specification says what to do.  Convention means that pretty much everybody does it a certain way or that it defaults to a certain way.   I'm not sure either of those apply in this case.  It is probably just a matter of opinion about how to best say your business name when you can't use the ampersand symbol.

Comment: I improved the question based on distinction you mentioned. Formal alternative or convention; , I was not sure whether there was a general chosen pattern in such a case. There is no "formal" alternative as far as I could find but I'm curious whether there is a "convention" that can be opted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few options for an `&` in a domain name:

- Leave it out: `xxbusiness.example`
- Spell out the word "and": `xandxbusiness.example`
- Spell out the word "and" plus use hyphens: `x-and-x-business.example`
- Replace it with an allowed character like `-`: `x-xbusiness.example`
- Change the name of your business to be more domain-name-friendly (advocated by the answer to [Is an ampersand (&) in a company name not ideal for Google or SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71791/is-an-ampersand-in-a-company-name-not-ideal-for-google-or-seo))

In most cases that I've seen, businesses just leave the `&` out of the URL.  Here are a few famous examples:

- AT&T: `att.com`
- B&H Photo: `bhphotovideo.com`
- M&M'S: `mms.com`

But there are exceptions, maybe because the shorter domain name without the ampersand wasn't available:

- C&A: `c-and-a.com`

Comment: "maybe because the shorter domain name without the ampersand wasn't available:" two letters domain names are often reserved, and especially if they represent a country ISO code, like `ca`. Of course things are slightly different/more complicated for `com` where anyway all short combinations were taken long before the rules were set up.

Comment: H&M has `hm.com`

Comment: Now 2 letter .com new domaind are reserved, but many were already registered, and still in use. X.com fb.com